# No auto-completion in VS Code with Python extension (using Pylance)

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, pylance

I'm getting started with Python in VS Code. I've got the Python extension installed with IntelliSense from Pylance. Auto-completion has worked so far with some fairly simple pieces of code using built-in functions and methods, but now I'm playing with NumPy and auto-complete doesn't behave like I would expect. I've got the following piece of code:

```
import numpy as np

grid = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
```

When typing "np." the auto-completion works perfectly, but when arriving at "np.arange(20)." nothing happens.

What am I missing? Thanks a lot!

**Edited (additional info): works in other cases**
It does somehow work for this case:

```
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 3).<autocomplete works here>
```

**Edited (additional info): differs per environment**
Apparently it differs per environment (I use Anaconda).

- First screenshot: Python 3.9.7 + numpy 1.20.3 ('base')
- Second screenshot: Python 3.10.4 + numpy 1.21.5 ('clean')

[image: Python 3.9.7 + numpy 1.20.3]

[image: Python 3.10.4 + numpy 1.21.5]

Comment: what is the type `arange()` returns, use the tooltip

Comment: `arange(stop: Any, dtype: ... = ..., *, like: ... = ...) -> Any`

Comment: return type is `Any`, how do you suppose Intellisence will auto suggest you something

Comment: I already thought that was the problem when you asked the question. Sorry, newbie question...

Comment: my setup gives all 11 variants of `arange` a result of `NDArray` of some type, I use PyLance too, and it gives suggestions after typing `.`

Comment: I added a screenshot to the description of the question. To me it gives two variants both returning `Any`.

Comment: I use a regular `.py` file, no Notebook, try the Interactive Python file with `#%%` comments

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but when I run ipython from terminal (conda base env) and then type `import numpy as np` and then `np.arange(20.<tab>` then auto-completion does work. In VS Code it doesn't matter if I'm in a notebook or a regular .py file: both don't work.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be the same problem as sachit-menon mentions [here](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1847) on 29 June 2020.

Comment: @luukburger This problem on github is still open.  There is no solution at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem this issue is the same as [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1714). Updating numpy to version >= 1.22 seems to fix it.

For context, Pylance uses Pyright under the hood to provide completions, and in this it's relying on typing information provided by numpy itself. It looks like the newest versions of numpy has improved typing info, which solves the problem.

Comment: You're the best, updating to 1.22.3 fixed the issue. Thank a lot!